# how to make DLL acess a class/object in the exe applicaiton in which it is loaded

Tags: c#, dll

I have a C# exe application which loads a DLL runtime, i would like to know how can DLL access a public static class of the Application ??

Comment: You can't. The application needs a reference to the DLL, and the DLL would need a reference to the application. This creates a circular reference, which can't be handled.

Comment: A DLL is usually created for reusability purpose and hence should not have reference to a specific application. What are you trying to acheive?

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be sloved with a third DLL containing only contracts and commonly used stuff. I would declare an interface in a contracts assembly and inject an object implementing it into the dynamically loaded classes.

You cannot use a static class, as those cannot implement interfaces. If you need something static then use the singleton pattern.

```
// In the Contracts assembly

// Defines the same functionality as was in your static class.
public interface IServiceContract
{
    void SomeServiceMethod();
}

// For the classes dynamically loaded from the DLL
public interface IAddIn
{
    void TestMethod();
}
```

---

```
// In the dynamically loaded assembly

public class AddInClass : IAddIn
{
    private IServiceContract _service;

    public AddInClass(IServiceContract service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    public void TestMethod()
    {
        _service.SomeServiceMethod();
    }
}
```

---

```
// In the main assembly (exe)

public class ImplementsServiceContract : IServiceContract
{
    public void SomeServiceMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello world!");
    }
}
```

usage

```
IServiceContract service = new ImplementsServiceContract();

Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\myDll.dll");
var type = assembly.GetType("AddInClass");
IAddIn addIn = (IAddIn)Activator.CreateInstance(type, service);

addIn.TestMethod();
```

Answer (score 0):

This would generally done by the dll providing an interface, and the main application implementing that interface then passing an instance of the implementation back to the dll's code.

So for example, in the library(dll):

```
public interface IDependency
{
    void DoThing();
}

public class MyLibraryClass
{
    IDependency _dependency;

    public MyLibraryClass(IDependency dependency)
    {
        _dependency = dependency;
    }

    public void MyUsefulMethod()
    {
        //Some stuff
        _dependency.DoThing();
        //Some more stuff
    }
}
```

Then in the application code:

```
public class ConcreteDependency : IDependency
{
    public void DoThing()
    {
        //Implementation here
    }
}

public class MyClassThatUsesTheLibrary()
{
    public void MyMethod()
    {
        var dependency = new ConcreteDependency();
        var libraryClass = new MyLibraryClass(dependency);
        libraryClass.MyUsefulMethod();
    }
}
```

Since static classes can't directly implement interfaces, you'd need to use the **adapter pattern** in that case. Have a class which does implement the interface and just passes its calls through to the static class's methods.